# How to show that sums of simple functions are in $L^p$?

Tags: measure-theory

If $u = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} c_k 1_{A_k}$
I can show this to be measurable or not, and I can show whether it's integrable or not. But what about whether it lies in $L^p$, p > 1?

My problem is that I am taking an infinite sum to a power and then taking an integral, and I'd like to know how to work around that so that we can get the power on each term instead of on the entire sum?

Comment: I have always seen simple functions defined as finite conical combinations of characteristic functions of measurable sets. Emphasis on *finite*.

Comment: Yes, and $u = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty c_k1_{A_k}$ is a sum of simple functions, as written in the title of the question, if the $A_k$s are measurable, since $c_k1_{A_k}$ is a finite combination of characteristic functions, and thus a simple function. Emphasis on $\textit{finite}$.

Comment: Ah, misread the question, sorry.

Comment: Even a single simple function need not be in $L^p$ for any $p<\infty$. Take for instance $\chi_{\mathbb R}$ with Lebesgue measure.

Comment: I am not looking for counter-examples. In general, how does one show it? Take any example, e.g. $u = \sum_{i \ge 1} \frac{1}{i}1_{[i,1+i]}$. Is this in $L^2$, say?